# Restart a service when the main process exits

Tags: systemd

I am using [grabserial](https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial) to log serial data from a device. I have set up a continuous logging service as per the instructions provided in the following documentation [continuous logging](https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial/blob/master/continuous_logging.md)

The grabserial tool has an option that allows you to quit the program when the output matches a given string. For example, the following command will exit when grabserial reads a line that starts with "Exit".

```
grabserial -q "^Exit" -d /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So, my question is how do I restart the service when grabserial which is the main process exits (after detecting the "Exit" string from the serial port)?

I have read the documentation on [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and tried various options such as `KillMode=mixed` etc, but none have worked for me. Killing the process manually using `sudo kill [PID of grabserial]` triggers a restart of the service, but when grabserial exits based on string matching, the service fails to restart and it continues to run.

Below is my service file. I have used the same service file as per the documentation provided above except that I have added the -`q "^Exits"` argument.

```
[Unit]
Description=Serial Data Logging Service
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.3-0000:07:00.0-usb3-3\x2d1-3\x2d1:1.0-ttyUSB0-tty-ttyUSB0.device
BindsTo=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.3-0000:07:00.0-usb3-3\x2d1-3\x2d1:1.0-ttyUSB0-tty-ttyUSB0.device

[Service]
Type=simple
GuessMainPID=no
KillMode=process
Environment=PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/grabserial -v -Q -q "^Exit" -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -o "/var/grabserial/LoggingData-%%Y%%m%%d.log" -A
TimeoutSec=2
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=2 3
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog+console
SyslogIdentifier=GrabSerial
User=grabserial
Group=grabserial
SupplementaryGroups=dialout
PermissionsStartOnly=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.3-0000:07:00.0-usb3-3\x2d1-3\x2d1:1.0-ttyUSB0-tty-ttyUSB0.device
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Try [`Restart=always`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) instead of `Restart=on-failure`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked after removing the -a option from grabserial. The -a option was prevented grabserial from exiting.

Comment: Great!,  I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> So, my question is how do I restart the service when grabserial which is the main process exits (after detecting the "Exit" string from the serial port)?

You can use `Restart=always`

[`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) shows:

```
          Table 2. Exit causes and the effect of the Restart= settings on them
           ┌──────────────┬────┬────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
           │Restart       │ no │ always │ on-success │ on-failure │ on-abnormal │ on-abort │ on-watchdog │
           │settings/Exit │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           │causes        │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           ├──────────────┼────┼────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
           │Clean exit    │    │ X      │ X          │            │             │          │             │
           │code or       │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           │signal        │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           ├──────────────┼────┼────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
           │Unclean exit  │    │ X      │            │ X          │             │          │             │
           │code          │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           ├──────────────┼────┼────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
           │Unclean       │    │ X      │            │ X          │ X           │ X        │             │
           │signal        │    │        │            │            │             │          │             │
           ├──────────────┼────┼────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
           │Timeout       │    │ X      │            │ X          │ X           │          │             │
           ├──────────────┼────┼────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
           │Watchdog      │    │ X      │            │ X          │ X           │          │ X           │
           └──────────────┴────┴────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
```

Since you already have `on-failure` and you want to restart when `grabserial` exist normally, it means you need to add the `on-success` condition.  `always` is perfect for you.

You've also indicated that this only works if you remove `-a` from `grabserial`.